# UVM_INFO returning a HEX value

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, uvm

I use this command to print the contents of the transaction class in Questasim:

```
`uvm_info("VALUES", tx.sprint(), UVM_LOW)
```

My transaction has a variable `ans`.  The problem is it is printing it as HEX rather than DECIMAL.

It shows:

`ans  integral        8     'h1c`

How can I get it to display it as:

```
ans  integral        8     'd28
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the UVM_DEC flag when register your uvm class:

```
`uvm_object_utils_begin(your_class)
`uvm_field_int(ans, UVM_ALL_ON | UVM_DEC)
`uvm_object_utils_end
```

Comment: Its working
But one small problem..
some times instead of 'd12 it is displaying only 12.Like this mostly for all number greater than 7.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the inefficiency of uvm_field_macros, it would be best to overwrite the convert2string() method, and specify the format as you wish.