# how to print integral value in decimal format using uvm_printer rather default hex format

Tags: uvm

```
class dpcfg extends uvm_object;
  rand int num_lanes;

  function new(string name="");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction

  function void do_print(uvm_printer printer);
    printer.print_string("dpcfg", "dpcfg");
    printer.print_field("num_lanes", num_lanes, $bits(num_lanes));
  endfunction

endclass

//Instantiating the above class
dpcfg cfg;
cfg = new("cfg");
cfg.print();
```

I am getting the print output as below

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Name                Type      Size  Value     
 ----------------------------------------------
 cfg                 dpcfg     -     @2579     
   dpcfg             string    5     dpcfg     
   num_lanes         integral  32    'hA 
 ----------------------------------------------
```

where I need print output as below

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Name                Type      Size  Value     
 ----------------------------------------------
 cfg                 dpcfg     -     @2579     
   dpcfg             string    5     dpcfg     
   num_lanes         integral  32    'd10 
 ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229884/uvm-info-returning-a-hex-value The first answer seems to be the bkm.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
printer.print_field("num_lanes", num_lanes, $bits(num_lanes), UVM_DEC);
```

The prototype for `print_field` is:

```
  // Function: print_field
  //
  // Prints an integral field (up to 4096 bits).
  //
  // name  - The name of the field. 
  // value - The value of the field.
  // size  - The number of bits of the field (maximum is 4096). 
  // radix - The radix to use for printing. The printer knob for radix is used
  //           if no radix is specified. 
  // scope_separator - is used to find the leaf name since many printers only
  //           print the leaf name of a field.  Typical values for the separator
  //           are . (dot) or [ (open bracket).

  extern virtual function void print_field (string          name, 
                                            uvm_bitstream_t value, 
                                            int    size, 
                                            uvm_radix_enum radix=UVM_NORADIX,
                                            byte   scope_separator=".",
                                            string type_name="");
```

How do I know this? From the HTML documentation that comes with UVM. It's really, really good and then, if in doubt, you can click through to the UVM code itself.

Answer (score 0):

adding UVM_DEC solved the issue

```
function void do_print(uvm_printer printer);
  printer.print_string("dpcfg", "dpcfg");
  printer.print_field("num_lanes", num_lanes, $bits(num_lanes), UVM_DEC);
endfunction
```